# How to build the output encoded file using Huffman encoding algorithm?

Tags: encoding, huffman-code

I have a simple program which has in input a TXT file containing the string "Hello world" within. I just want to compress this file to have a gain of memory space. To do that, I have coded the huffman algorithm. My program is able to open the target file, and log the encoded string (Hello world) with characters '0' and '1'. However, I would like to create an output file which will contain the binary code (but, of course, not with characters). But I don't know how to do that. Does anyone can help me, please ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: what language are you programming in?

Comment: My program is coded in C++

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you any examples, as I dont know C++ and most things I've done with binary have failed..

The output of your function should be a multiple of 8 (as there 8 bits in a byte)

You need to loop through your output converting each 8 bits into a byte (char). It might be better to modify your encoding function to do this step for you, buffering the output.

When saving you might need to force an endian (eg: encoding it to big-endian) so that when you come to read and decode the data later you'll know how its encoded.